# How to run a repetitive task in parallel in Spark instead of looping sequentially?

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, apache-spark-sql

I have just started with Spark, and I know that non-functional way of sequential looping should be avoided for Spark to give me maximum performance.

I have a function `makeData`. I need to create a dataframe with the return value of this function by calling this function n times. Currently, my code looks like this:

```scala
var myNewDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row],  minority_set.schema)

for ( i <- 1 to n ) {
  myNewDF = myNewDF.unionAll(sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(makeData()),minority_set.schema))
}
```

Is there a way of doing this where each iteration happens in parallel?
Here the problem is that n can be large, and this loop is taking a lot of time. Is there a more scala/spark friendly way of achieving the same thing?

Comment: how does `makeData` look like, for me this code does not make much sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all your dataset is in memory already (guessing by `sc.parallelize(makeData())`) there's **no** point of using Spark SQL's `unionAll` to do the unioning which is also local (yet partitioned!).

I'd use Scala alone and only when you merged all the records I'd build a Dataset from it.

With that, I'd do something as follows:

```
val dataset = (1 to n).par.map { _ => makeData() }.reduce (_ ++ _)
val df = sc.parallelize(dataset, minority_set.schema)
```

Comment: what if `dataset` does not fit into the drivers memory? Maybe thats the reson for the unionAll (i.e. to distribute the data onto the executors)

Comment: I'd say that `sc.parallelize(makeData())` makes your comment void, i.e. the data is in memory already. I can't think of `makeData` to be as much lazy so Spark could help here in any way. I'd accept to be mistaken.

Comment: was just an idea, maybe the data returned by `makeData` does fit into memory, but not `n` times for large `n`

Comment: In either case, `sc.parallelize` will load it to memory and `unionAll` keeps it there. Hard to think of a use case where it made sense. Again, I'd love being told I'm mistaken (and learn something today...again).